# Android Vietnamese Text to Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, southeast-asian-languages

I am looking a way to develop an app in Android which speaks Vietnamese from texts. As I know there is no Vietnamese TTS installed by default. So is there any Vietnamese TTS engine for Android around there ?
One more thing : I pretend even I have Vietnamese TTS engine installed but the method `mTts.setLanguage(Locale)` requires a suitable locale and Vietnamese locale is not in the suggestion list. Is there a workaround solution for this case ?

Comment: you can create custom locales in the emulator.

Comment: You must install a TTS engine which supports Vietnamese. When you had it, you could do tts.setLanguage(new Locale("vi"));

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like this because it is not avaible a vietnamese tts language library.
You have to wait if google will develop something like this. Or maybe you can try to do this by your own.